# How to fix fatal error in joomla 1.0?

Tags: php, joomla, fatal-error

This is the error:

```
Warning: require_once(/home/exhibit/public_html/includes/version.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home2/exhibit/public_html/includes/joomla.php on line 71

Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required '/home/exhibit/public_html/includes/version.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home2/exhibit/public_html/includes/joomla.php on line 71
```

how to solve it?

Comment: the file /home/exhibit/public_html/includes/version.php exists ? if the answer is yes ' try set permission

Answer (score 0):

/home/exhibit/public_html/includes/version.php

Sometimes FTP times out when uploading a file and this file might not have been uploaded correctly. Check that this file has a filesize larger than 0 and that it's there at all. If not then simply reupload this file to the correct spot.